# Unable to change format of date in swift

Tags: swift, date, dateformatter

I am getting date `2019-01-02 18:10:00 +0000` like this now i want to convert it to `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm` format but i'm unable to get it.

I am using this method in date extension

```
func getDate() -> Date {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
    let dateString = formatter.string(from: self)
    return formatter.date(from: dateString) ?? Date()
}
```

when xcode executes this line

```
let dateString = formatter.string(from: self)
```

the result is in format which i want but when last line gets executed date returns back to the old formate

Comment: Are you sending this date to the server? There are well established conventions for exchanging date strings with a server, i.e., ISO8601 and RFC 3999. It’s usually in a format of `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX"` (i.e. which would produce string of "2019-01-02T19:23:31Z”). If this date format that your server is currently accepting isn’t chiseled into stone, you probably should consider using a more standard convention, like shown here. By the way, if you do that, you can also use `ISO8601DateFormatter` which gets you out of the weeds of setting formatter strings, locales, timezones, etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. If you need to show the date, you use a formatted `String` and not the `Date` object.

```
func getDate() -> String {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    // Set the appropriate time zone or locale
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
    return formatter.string(from: self)
}
```

Comment: @GulfamKhan obviously the server accepts a string and not a Swift `Date` object.

Comment: is there a way to get date in this format or not, the server requires it in date format

Comment: you are saying that this is a server end problem not on my side?

Comment: @GulfamKhan i am saying that your server accepts a **STRING** and certainly _not_ a Swift **DATE** object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186049/discussion-between-gulfam-khan-and-rakesha-shastri).

Comment: You should not set the timezone to UTC and you should not set this specific format because it will confuse many users. Users won't know whether something like `08/04/2018 14:56` is August 4th or April 8th and users won't know it is UTC time and not local time. Use a date and time style instead of an ambiguous date format. And either show the time in local time or include the timezone in the result if it isn't local time.

Comment: @rmaddy He said that this string is for consumption by server, not end user, in which case he most likely *should* set timezone and locale

Comment: @Rob I don't see anything in the question about that. But if so, yes, a specific format and timezone is appropriate. But then the locale should also be set to `en_US_POSIX` as well.

Comment: @rmaddy - Correct, he doesn’t mention it in the question, but he says so in his first comment under this answer.

Answer (score 5):

You are confused. A `Date` object does not have a format. It records a moment in time. You have to convert it to a date **String** to give it a format.

Your code does that, which is fine. However, the last thing you do is to convert it back to a `Date`, and to discard the formatted string that you created. That makes no sense.

It is very likely that the server requires a date String. You should rewrite your function to return a date String, as in Rakesha Shastri's answer.

Comment: Also note that creating a date formatter is a somewhat expensive operation. Your code creates a new date formatter every time. Better to make the function a function of the class that needs it, and save the DateFormatter to a lazy instance variable.